# Equivalence of exponent in functions?

Tags: functions, notation, exponentiation

Is there any way of indicating that a function is supposed to be applied a certain number of times? (In such a way that you repeatedly take the output and put it back into the function.)

Let's say for example you have a function $a(x,y)$ which is defined in such a way that $a(x,1) = b(x)$, $a(x,2) = b(b(x))$, $a(x,3) = b(b(b(x)))$ and so forth... could you then simply use exponentiation and write $a(x,y) = b(x)^y$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about what other people would use, but I would use something like $f^{(2)}(x)$ and $f^{(3)}(x)$. The $2$ and $3$ are in brackets so that they don't get confused with $[f(x)]^2$ and $[f(x)]^3$.

Comment: $b(b(b(x)))$ is certainly *not* $[b(x)]^3$ except for $b(x)=x^{\sqrt 3}$ (and maybe some few other strange exceptions). If your question is about notation, then use $b^{(3)}(x)$.

Comment: @Toby Mak I interpret your comment as there not being any set-in-stone standard notation for this within the mathematic community?

Comment: @user504882 Yes, I don't think there is any consensus for this kind of notation (that is widely accepted).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia entry [iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function), the $n$-th iterate of $f$ can be written as $f^n$, as long as you define it properly: this makes sense, if you consider the monoid of functions under composition.

Now, still quoting Wikipedia:

> Because the notation $f^n$ may refer to both iteration (composition)
>   of the function f or exponentiation of the function f (the latter is
>   commonly used in trigonometry), some mathematicians choose to write
>   $f^{\circ n}$ for the $n$-th iterate of the function $f$.

Finally, I fully agree with Toby Mak that $f^{(n)}$ is also of common use.

**Conclusion**. Whatever notation you choose, start by giving a precise definition to avoid any ambiguity. This definition can be very short, like "let $f^n$ denote the $n$-th iterate of the function $f$", but is mandatory.